# How to get Activity reference in ListView Adapter class?

Tags: android, listview, android-activity, android-context, listadapter

I am trying to request the phone call permission from the list adapter class on the click of a button which requires the Activity as the first argument.

```
 ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(mContext, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE},1 );
```

here the mContext is passed from one of the activity. but it show error :

```
Wrong 1st argument type. Found: 'android.content.Context', required: 'android.app.Activity'.
```

i tried to pass every context and also the getParent() activity but it's not working.
Is there any way to get the Activity and use it in list adapter ?.

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                dialNumber(employee.get(i).getNumber());
                }
            else
                {

                    Log.i(TAG, "onClick: you don't have permission to call");
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(mContext, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE},1 );
                }

                Log.i(TAG, "onClick: Wroks " + getItemId(i));

        }
```

this is the full code for button click listener.

Thankyou.

Comment: ActivityCompat.requestPermissions actually need instance of activity not context. change type of `mContext` Context to Activity.

Comment: i tried that too, but not working

Comment: Create an interface in your adapter class and pass a callback from the activity. So on button click the callback will come to the activity, now you can pass any context you want.

Comment: Are you inside an activity or inside a fragment? If the context comes from an activity you can cast it to activity by doing (Activity) mContext

Comment: @NicolaGallazzi list adapter class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having references of Activity in Adapter class is a bad approach. Anything that should be done within the activity class such as UI changes, displaying dialog etc. should not be done anywhere else but from the activity itself.

**Solution:**
1) Create an interface

```
public interface MyListener {
     void doSomething(Params... params);
}
```

2) Implement it in Activity class

```
class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MyListener{ 
       new MyAdapter(this);  

       void doSomething(Params... params){
             //Request Permission here
       }
}
```

3) Use like this in Adapter class

```
class MyAdapter extends .....{
      MyListener myListener;

      MyAdapter(Context mContext){
           if(mContext instanceOf MyListener)
                 myListener = (MyListener) mContext;
      }

      void anotherFunction(){
             myListener.doSomething(Params... params) 
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure the mContext is of type Activity, just cast it like this

```
ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission((Activity) mContext, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE)
```

Comment: i have to request for the permission checking is working properly.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the Activity context to Adapter constructor

like this // assuming you working in activity

```
 ListAdapter listAdapter = new ListAdapter(this)
```

in your adapter

```
 public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        Context context;
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

        public ListAdapter (Context context) {
            this.context = context;
     }
```

Now use the context where you want in adapter

```
ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission((Activity) context, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Above answer is so helpful but if context is not converting to activity and app is crashing on runtime as occurred in my case, then you can also pass activity through constructor of adapter class like this.

```
private Context context;
private ArrayList<String> pathsList;
private Activity activity;

public Adapter(Context context, Activity activity, ...) {
    this.context = context;
    this.activity = activity;
    ...
}
```

And then use this activity into your code:

```
ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, 
Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE);
```